# Can I avoid using `sudo` to back up files owned by root?

Tags: permissions, rsync, backup, ownership

I'm using `rsync` to back up a set of files in `/etc`. The 'source' files are on an `ext4` filesystem, and the 'destination' is an `ext4` partition on a USB thumb drive. My incantation is similar to this:

```
rsync -av --recursive --files-from=my/etcfiles /etc ./my/backup/etc/
```

Not unexpectedly, I get errors with this including:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/my/backup/etc/somefile": Operation not permitted (1)  
rsync: mkstemp "/my/backup/etc/somefile.erGL4a" failed: Permission denied (13)  
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

I think this is because the `a` option in `rsync` preserves ownership (root) of the files I'm backing up, and so root privileges are required to complete `rsync`'s operations.

This `rsync` operation completes successfully when run under `sudo`, but I need to set this up as a `cron` job, and using `sudo` in a `crontab` brings an issue (password storage) I'd like to avoid.

Another possibility may be changing ownership of the root-owned files (using the `chown=USER:GROUP` option) during the `rsync` backup. I've not tried that because it occurs to me that, even if it works without `sudo`, the ownership would have to be restored if the backups were ever needed.

I've been stewing over this for the better part of a day now, and growing weary of wrangling with `rsync`'s myriad options. So - My question is this:

How can I avoid using `sudo` to make backups of files in `/etc` without committing an even worse [***bodge***](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bodge)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up a [root cron job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419548/how-to-set-up-a-root-cron-job-properly) and then the script will run as root anyways. To access the root crontab, run `sudo crontab -e`.

Comment: I'm selecting this as the correct answer. I had hoped the use of `sudo` could be avoided entirely, but no answers have emerged to reflect that.